# how to set slider value over jquery or capybara

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, capybara

I am trying to set the slider value but I couldnt manage it. I am using Capybara, selenium driver. The html code is:

```
<div class="pslide-container">
    <div class="slider slider-horizontal" id="">
        <div class="slider-track">
            <div class="slider-selection" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div>
            <div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle triangle" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></div>
            <div class="slider-handle max-slider-handle triangle" tabindex="0" style="left: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip tooltip-main top hide" style="left: 50%; margin-left: 0px;">
            <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
            <div class="tooltip-inner">9 : 693</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip tooltip-min top hide" style="left: 0%; margin-left: 0px;">
            <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
            <div class="tooltip-inner">9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip tooltip-max hide top" style="top: -30px; left: 100%; margin-left: 0px;">
            <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
            <div class="tooltip-inner">693</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="priceselect" type="text" class="span2 priceslider" value="9,693" data-slider-min="90" data-slider-max="693" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[9,693]" data-slider-handle="triangle" data="value:'9,693'" style="display: none;">
        <b class="pull-left">
            <span id="minvalue">9</span>&nbsp;TL

        </b>
        <b class="pull-right">
            <span id="maxvalue">693</span>&nbsp;TL

        </b>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the `.slider("values", 0, 80)` but it doesnt work:

```
$('#priceselect').slider("values", 0, 80)
```

Bootstrap slider info:

```
/* =========================================================
 * bootstrap-slider.js
 *
 * Maintainers: 
 *      Kyle Kemp 
 *          - Twitter: @seiyria
 *          - Github:  seiyria
 *      Rohit Kalkur
 *          - Twitter: @Rovolutionary
 *          - Github:  rovolution
 *
 * =========================================================
```

Comment: have you tried just "value"? or `$("#slider").slider("option", "value", newValue);`

Comment: @ahervin it is not working, we have also bootstrap.

Comment: IIRC bootstrap doesn't have a slider control by default, so what slider widget are you using?

Comment: @TomWalpole sorry not sure about it.

Comment: Without knowing what widget you're using, or if you have custom JS running the slider, it's pretty much impossible to tell you how to set its value

Comment: @TomWalpole I added slider info, please check it. Guess it can help this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using bootstrap-slider by seiyria you can see instructions for using with jQuery [here](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#using-bootstrap-slider-with-jquery)

From skimming the documentation and examples I think the following should do what you want

```
$('#priceselect').slider('setValue', [0,80])
```

so to do that from Capybara you would do

```
page.execute_script("$('#priceselect').slider('setValue', [0,80])")
```

If you want slide and change events to be triggered you can pass true to 2 optional parameters, so

```
page.execute_script("$('#priceselect').slider('setValue', [0,80], true, true)")
```

will trigger both the slide and change events when setting the new value

Comment: thanks this works for changing the slider value but it doesnt work as setting it by hand. it is not filtering the pricelist.

Comment: What JS events is your filtering triggering on?

Comment: You can have the setValue trigger slide and change events -- added details to answer - you can see the functions the bootstrap-slider supports here - https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#functions

Comment: then you need to figure out what events you're actually triggering the filtering on since those same events should be what the widget generates when manually moving the sliders

Comment: Working like a charm!